# Comprehension list of nested dictionary to get values but got keys

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Fairly new to list comprehension and have `the_list` that I want to extract the keys of nested dictionary but I got the values instead. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

```
the_list = [{'size': 0, 'values': [], 'start': 0}, {'size': 2, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'anna', 'id': 10, 'displayName': 'Anna'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}, {'user': {'name': 'bob', 'id': 11, 'displayName': 'Bobby'}, 'category': 'Manager'}], 'start': 0}, {'size': 1, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'claire', 'id': 13, 'displayName': 'Clarissa Claire'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}], 'start': 0}]

list_comprehension = []
list_comprehension = [x for x in the_list for x in the_list[1]['values'][0]]
print(list_comprehension)

    >> ['user', 'category', 'user', 'category', 'user', 'category']
```

Want

```
list_comprehension = [[anna, Secretary], [bob, manager], [claire, Secretary]]
```

Comment: Why do you use `x` for two different things in the same list-comp? That's not readable and a recipe for disaster (even though it might actually work)

Comment: list comprehension is similar to math functions, so I used x. But you're right it's recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this. I personnally try to avoid nested list comprehension as they are hard to read and debug.

```py
[[x['category'], x['user']['displayName']] for nest_list in the_list for x in nest_list["values"] ]
```

Output:

```
[['Secretary', 'Anna'], ['Manager', 'Bobby'], ['Secretary', 'Clarissa Claire']]
```

**EDIT**:
A version that doesn't have a nested comprehension list. When doing it I realised that there was one more level than I realised that makes this version a bit long. So in the end I'm not sure which one I would use in prod.

```py
result = []
dict_list = [nest_list["values"] for nest_list in the_list]
for elt in dict_list:
    for d in elt:
        result.append([d['category'], d['user']['displayName']])
```

Comment: it actually works. Could I have done it more easily for myself some other ways to simplify before doing list comprehensions?

Comment: List comprehension is just a concise version of a for loop. I'll update the example the way I would write it for readability

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution, but it is not very readable ...

```
comprehensionList = [[user['user']['name'], user['category']] for x in the_list for user in x['values']]

# Output
[['anna', 'Secretary'], ['bob', 'Manager'], ['claire', 'Secretary']]
```